# Automatic copy in excel

Tags: excel

if i have in first three rows of column A data

A1 = 1

A2 = 2

A3 = 3

and drag it down in A4 will be 4, A5 = 5 and etc.

I want to do the same but with connection from another workbook. If i have in A1 = 1 from source ='C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[001.xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1

and in A2 = 2, from source ='C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[002.xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1

after i drag it i want:

A1 = C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[001.xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1

A2 = C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[002.xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1

A3 = C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[003.xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1

A4 = C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[004.xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1

A5 = etc.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `INDIRECT` function to achieve this. In your main spreadsheet:

- Enter `'001` in Cell A1 (the apostrophe will stop Excel from converting to number)
- Enter `="C:\Users\chrast_m\Desktop\Kalibrácia[" & A1 & ".xlsx]Hárok1'!$AA$1"`
- Enter `=INDIRECT(B1)` in Cell C1

Now if you select cells A1:C1 and drag them down, you will create references to 002.xlsx, 003.xlsx etc.

Comment: If you click on cell C1, what does the alert say? In my spreadsheet, I only have the green triangle in col A (due to having the apostrophe).

Comment: Also, you will need the other workbooks open for the links to work. That may be your issue.

Comment: displacement or removal of cells cause invalide reference. Open workbook is not the problem.

Comment: Try selecting another cell in your main workbook, typing = and then navigating to one of the $AA$1 cells in one of the target workbooks. The string you are building in col B must match the formula you just generated. If they match, then you shouldn't be getting an error in Col C.